# Eigen Function Question

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $R[X]_n \;$ be the Vector Space of Polynomials $degree <=n$

$T : R[X]_n \rightarrow R[X]_n$

$f(x) \rightarrow f(ax+b)$

How Do I conclude that the Eigenvalues of this Operator are $1,a,.....a^n$

Trying to make sense of $f(ax+b) = \lambda \; f(x)$ gets me nowhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the matrix of$~T$ with respect to the most obvious basis $1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^n$, and observe that it is upper triangular with diagonal entries $1,a,\ldots,a^n$. What does this tell you about the characteristic polynomial of$~T$?